# In application picker, it is NOT showing applications like whatsapp, facebook messenger etc

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I want to share excel file.  In applications picker, it is showing applications like GMAIL, EMAIL app but it not showing Whatsapp or facebook messenger. Here is my code. What additional thing do I need to mention?

```
Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
File fileInDownloads = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),FILE);

intentShareFile.setType("application/excel");
intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(fileInDownloads));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Share File"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `WhatsApp` or `Facebook` simply didn't register themselves as apps that can share `Excel` files. Remember that they would have needed to do something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/excel" />
</intent-filter>
```

but didn't. Maybe you can upload the file to somewhere (e.g. Google Drive) and share a link to it?

You can also try something like this:

```
intentShareFile.setType("*/*");
```

Comment: when I have an excel file in my mobile, and when i click on share button, it DOES show me whatsapp, and other apps as an option.

Comment: @RadhikaParmar In which app do you share the Excel file?

Comment: whatsapp. Anyway, what is the solution?

Comment: Hi @RadhikaParmar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is because those apps didn't define an Intent Filter to process that kind of MIME types. That's by design from the developer and there's nothing you can do to avoid it.

Comment: what is the solution then? However, excel file can be shared from phone from file manager and shows all possible applications in the picker. 
In my android app, on clicking share button, it should show all possible applications but only few are shown. Please guide.

Comment: There's no solution because there's no problem, those apps don't allow you to send excel files from other app.

Comment: @MartinRevert That's not true, I just checked with the app `SolidExplorer` and you can share `Excel` (and many other files) to WhatsApp

Comment: I'm telling you the way things are expected to be if you respect other developers decisions and if you're a "good citizen" of the Android ecosystem. If you want to hack things over other Android Devs decisions or use a root app to explain your decisions, don't treat me like I'm not telling the truth.

Comment: @MartinRevert I'm not using a root app - my phone isn't even rooted, it works out of the box. And if it's a good or bad thing to do is another question.